# Messaging for In-App and Web - Agents unavailable

Tags: liveagent

I made an implementation of Messaging for In App & Web according to the Salesforce documentation, but when I click on the chat the message appears that there are no active agents, but inside the queue that was created there are agents that will serve the customers. Has anyone dealt with something like this?

[image]

Comment: Did you make the agent online in omniconsole?

Comment: were you even able to successfully add the messaging for web? did you put it into Salesforce public site or Salesforce Experience Cloud portal or external site?

Answer (score 0):

I came accross a similar issue. You'd need to make sure the Omni-channel flow is set properly, as well as the required fallback queue and routing configs. It depends if you want to route to a bot, an agent or a queue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to connect the chat to Bot and I was getting the same error.
First, I would suggest you to check the Flow errors, but anyway I solved by making sure that:

- The Fallback Queue had a Routing Configuration associated to it
- The Fallback Queue had Messaging Session as supported Object